# Arquillian jboss testng container and Junit tests

Tags: java, junit, testng, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

I want to run JUnit tests in jboss arquillian testng container. Is it possible to have junit test methods when having arquillian jboss testng container and then write all tests in JUnit? I mean something like this.

```
import org.jboss.arquillian.testng.Arquillian;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestClass extends Arquillian{

    @Test
    public void testMehtod1(){
        //something to test 1
    }

    @Test
    public void testMehtod2(){
        //something to test 2
    }

    @Test
    public void testMehtod3(){
        //something to test 3
    }

}
```

I will appreciate any answer

Comment: I don't think this is possible and the question is really why you would even try to do so? Why don't you just use the JUnit container?

Comment: I checked and this is not possible. I wanted to add to my project Arquillian TestRunner TestNG Container and not modify JUnit tests. 

But is it possible in the same project to have two classes with integration tests :
- first extending Arquillian(testng) like in example above
- second with org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian annotation

    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    @RunWith(Arquillian.class)
    public class SecondTest

without having conflict:
Multiple TestRunners found, only one allowed. Check your classpath